# Is sponge the first big SO clone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, clone

Mint recently added a Q&A section and it feels really familiar:  http://answers.mint.com/questions

The website footer says it's ["Powered by Sponge"](http://getsponge.com/).

Has the world starting becoming better* for Q&A sites?

```
* "better" as defined by Jeff being the death of phpBB
```

Answer (score 1):

[CNProg.com](http://www.cnprog.com/) has been around for some time.

Comment: How about as a non-computer related Q&A?

Comment: People keep​​​​ bringing that one up... I wanted to answer a question there, for the challenge, it isn't too active. It wasn't updated in days, and has few questions: http://www.cnprog.com/tags/

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the blog post where Sponge was announced](http://www.quicksprout.com/2010/02/16/introducing-quick-sprout-answers/). It's known as *Quick Sprout Answers* and seems to be maintained by [Neil Patel of Quick Sprout](http://www.quicksprout.com/about/). In the comments, Neil says "[Quick Sprout Answers is] similar [to StackExchange] in some ways but very different in most":

> **ziker February 16, 2010 at 5:51 PM**
>
> It’s exactly the same thing as
>   stackoverflow with less features.
>
> **Kevin February 16, 2010 at 6:36 PM**
>
> I wouldn’t say exactly. I havn’t seen a
>   stackoverflow/stackexchange site look
>   this good.
>
> Props Neil!
>
> **Neil Patel February 18, 2010 at 9:06 PM**
>
> This was a custom job.
>
> **Neil Patel February 18, 2010 at 9:06 PM**
>
> its similar in some ways but very
>   different in most.

FWIW I completely disagree with that Kevin guy who said he's never seen a SE site look so good. Pffft.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an account to do any Q&A, so it's not a complete clone. Instead, it's a complete fail. OpenID FTW!

Comment: Ouch... Either somebody really loves Sponge or really hates OpenID.

Comment: There is more to life than OpenID and no-registration-required (I'm the second downvote). For a real comparison this is almost irrelevant

Comment: @Randolpho: Add a screen cap of Sponge with some FHC and I'm sure you'll get some upvotes to compensate... this is Meta after all ;-)

Comment: @Earlz: I think Randolpho's point was, w/o openid it's not a complete clone

Comment: @Josh: something like that. Sponge does not implement one of the biggest selling points of SOFU, which is the use of OpenID. Instead it offers yet another stupid account to have to juggle. Because of this lack of feature, Sponge is fail. @Earlz can downvote me all he likes, it doesn't change that fact.

Comment: @Earlz: on the contrary, the use of OpenID / the allowance of anonymous posting is one of the single biggest selling points of SOFU.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you're saying now. I thought you meant "they are in no way similar because of that small detail". So true it isn't a complete clone, but I'm sure that wouldn't be so difficult to implement if they wanted it to be "complete" in your book

Comment: @Earlz: It'd certainly take the site up a notch in my book.

Comment: @Randol well at least they aren't charging you to see the answers like some sites.

Comment: @Earlz: On the site you refer to, the answers come free with every sex change you purchase ;-)